# AngularJs: sharing model data between directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just can't seem to grok the appropriate bindings in Angular directives. I have the following code:

html

```
<div ng-app="choreApp">
    <div ng-controller="ChoreCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat='chore in Chores'>
          <h2 announce clicky-thing='updateName({chore: chore})' style='color: {{chore.color}}'>{{chore.name}} <== chore </h2>   
        </div>

        <hr />
        <input type="text" ng-model='chore.name' />
        <input type="text" ng-model='chore.color' />
        <br />
        <button ng-click='updateName({chore: chore})'>Update Name to {{Chore.name}}</button>




     </div>
</div>
```

// javascript

```
var app = angular.module("choreApp", []);

app.controller("ChoreCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.Chores = [
        {name: 'Dude', color: 'blue'},
        {name: 'Guy', color: 'black'},
        {name: 'Dudette', color: 'red'},
        {name: 'Gal', color: 'orange'}
    ];


    $scope.updateName = function (chore) {
        alert('okay ' + chore.name);
    };
});


app.directive("announce", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            clickyThing: '&'
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {

            elem.bind('click', function () {
                scope.clickyThing({chore: chore});
            });
        }
    };
});
```

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/k8xYX/14/

There are four h2, each which are bound to their own `chore` object. What I want is to be able to click one of the h2's, bind that individual `chore` to the controller's scope (and fill in the inputs with the `chore`'s model data), make an update to one of the input elements, click the 'Update Name' button and have that model data update the h2 that was clicked.

Comment: first of all your output is Dude <== chore, Guy <== chore.... is it right? or it should be Dude<==Blue, Guy<==Black??

Comment: the output is weird (it's the result of a weird journey in this code), but it's correct. It could easily be changed to <=== {{chore.color}} and be fine

Comment: your object is {chore: chore}, therefore you should reference in the alert as chore.chore.name rather than chore.name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an updated fiddle:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BFB7R/)

Updated Directive:

```
app.directive("announce", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            clickyThing: '&',
            chore: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            var chore = scope.chore;
            elem.bind('click', function () {

                scope.clickyThing(chore);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Problems addressed:

> 1. You've declared an isolated scope for the announce directive, but haven't imported the 'chore' model into your isolated scope - yet you reference chore when you execute the clickyThing(). I've changed it so that your directive imports the 'chore' model.
> 2. You use { chore: chore } as the model passed to your click handlers - this is not necessary. I've changed this so that it passes the model directly.
> 3. Within the updateName() method, its being called from outside the Angular context, so I've wrapped the assignment of chore in an $apply block. This ensures that a $digest is triggered after the execution of the code.

I agree with Kevin, you should probably use ng-click instead.

Comment: have you check your fiddle?

Comment: it gives $digest error when clicking on update to button after changing the color value.

Comment: the $scope.$apply (and associated explanation) helped a lot. Is it idomatic to define a model within a method? Would it be better to define $scope.chore under $scope.Chore (appreciating that it's bad naming)?

Comment: Yes, defining models and assigning them to scope is idiomatic inside a controller.  Alternatively, the model can come from a service/factory - also acceptable and good practice. I would use lower-case for model names as a naming convention.

Comment: Yes i must appreciate the way example has been done by poxelbits. & its pretty working well. no problem. but what if I change color and press below button? it give $diegest error which is wrong.

Comment: @micronyks Yes, there is a $digest error. I leave it to the OP to conditionally call $apply.  One method invocation is calling the method within the Angular context, the other is not.

Comment: Bryce, have you got what you wanted? or want anything more?

Answer (score 2):

your object is `{chore: chore}`, therefore you should reference in the alert as chore.chore.name rather than chore.name.

```
$scope.updateName = function (chore) {
    alert('okay ' + chore.chore.name);
    //$scope.Chore.color = 'pink';
};
```

Alternatively you could change the way you're passing it in:

```
clicky-thing='updateName(chore)'
```

Additionally, $scope.clickyThing actually references an executable function that contains a function created using the text inside of the clicky-thing attribute, you just need to execute it without any arguments.

```
elem.bind('click', function () {
    scope.clickyThing();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k8xYX/16/

Unless you're doing more than executing the passed in code though, you should probably instead simply use an ng-click.

Comment: +1 for the ng-click in this example. The example is contrived and representative of a bigger solution.